# Mongodb $lookup Aggregation Query takes 11+ seconds, How do I optimise this

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a stock price alerts application with 3 collections

1) Alerts

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9543c235434a185038e778"), //alert id
    "1" : ObjectId("5a9543c035434a185038e743"), //user id
    "2" : "xyz", //asset id
    "3" : "EUR", //fiat set by the user
    "4" : NumberDecimal("1000"), //price at which user wants alert
    "5" : true, // true if 1000 was greater than price at the time of setting the alert
    "6" : 0, //type 0 indicating it is a price alert
    "__v" : 0
}
```

2) Asset value in USD which updates every 2 mins, has **2000** assets currently

```
{
    "_id" : "xyz", //asset id
    "1" : 997, //current price of the asset
}
```

3) Fiat conversions from USD which updates hourly, has **160** currencies currently

```
{
    "_id" : "EUR",
    "1" : 0.811798
}
```

A person must be able to set an alert saying "Alert me if xyz in EUR falls below 1000 or rises above 1000"

For test data, I set up 100000 alerts and the first step is to find the current price of the asset xyz from the assets table for which I did a join

```
 Alert
        .aggregate([
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "assets",
                    localField: "2", //field containing asset id
                    foreignField: "_id", //foreign field with asset id
                    as: "s"
                }

            }
        ])

        .allowDiskUse(true)

        .exec((error, result) => {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            else {
                console.log("Got", result.length, "documents mongoose")
            }
            mongoose.connection.close()
        })
```

**This alone takes 11 seconds currently!**

I want to be able to multiply the current prices of each asset with the specified currency and then check if it is above or below the level set by the user in order to trigger the alert

For example, if the alert is xyz:EUR, i want to get the asset price of XYZ in USD, the price of USD to EUR and multiply both to get the final price xyz:EUR and check if this value is greater than or less than 1000 to trigger the alert

The foreign field is an _id field which I assume is indexed by default. I have set an index on the localField 2: which is my asset id and 3: which is my fiat symbol

Here is the result of **getIndexes()** query on my target

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.alerts"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "2" : 1
        },
        "name" : "2_1",
        "ns" : "test.alerts",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "3" : 1
        },
        "name" : "3_1",
        "ns" : "test.alerts",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

I also ran an **explain()** to check what is happening and it indicates a COLLSCAN despite setting an index

```
{
        "stages": [
                {
                        "$cursor": {
                                "query": {},
                                "queryPlanner": {
                                        "plannerVersion": 1,
                                        "namespace": "test.alerts",
                                        "indexFilterSet": false,
                                        "parsedQuery": {},
                                        "winningPlan": {
                                                "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                                                "direction": "forward"
                                        },
                                        "rejectedPlans": []
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                        "$lookup": {
                                "from": "assets",
                                "as": "s",
                                "localField": "2",
                                "foreignField": "_id"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok": 1
}
```

Any suggestion, advice will be really helpful. Thank you

**Alternative**

One alternative which I really don't want to be doing is calculate all prices in code and add another field to the alerts collection called price which gets updated every 2 mins for xyz:EUR and other alerts. The potential 1500 assets x 160 fiats would mean a lot of entries every 2 mins to upsert

**Update 1 Profiler Output**

The keys are not being used! Any ideas

```
getmore test.e1_sources 89ms Tue Feb 27 2018 19:22:28
command:{
    "getMore" : NumberLong("6524439989055389783"),
    "collection" : "alerts",
    "batchSize" : 1000,
    "$readPreference" : {
        "mode" : "secondaryPreferred"
    },
    "$db" : "test"
} originatingCommand:{
    "aggregate" : "alerts",
    "pipeline" : [
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "assets",
                "localField" : "2",
                "foreignField" : "_id",
                "as" : "s"
            }
        }
    ],
    "allowDiskUse" : true,
    "cursor" : {
        "batchSize" : 1000
    },
    "$db" : "test"
} cursorid:NumberLong("6524439989055389783") keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted numYield:2 locks:{
    "Global" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(6000)
        }
    },
    "Database" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(3000)
        }
    },
    "Collection" : {
        "acquireCount" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(2999)
        }
    }
} nreturned:1000 responseLength:164393 protocol:op_query planSummary:COLLSCAN client:127.0.0.1 allUsers:[ ] user:
```

Answer (score 1):

A person must be able to set an alert saying "Alert me if xyz in EUR falls below 1000 or rises above 1000"

Based on the above line you have mentioned. add a match stage to filter assetid for that user id. which would reduce the amount of data you have to join.

```
Alert.aggregate([
            {
                $match:{
                     "1"://user id,
                     "2"://asset id
                     }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "assets",
                    localField: "2", //field containing asset id
                    foreignField: "_id", //foreign field with asset id
                    as: "s"
                }

            }
        ])

        .allowDiskUse(true)

        .exec((error, result) => {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            else {
                console.log("Got", result.length, "documents mongoose")
            }
            mongoose.connection.close()
        })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the one major issue is that I need to trigger all the alerts set up various users every 2 mins, the alerts are not just for a single user, i have noticed that localField does not use any index regardless of whether you set up one or not

Comment: when using a lookup which means left join, it doesn't use index on local field because you are joining all values in left table to right table based on a column. thats why it does a oollscan.